# How to detect hologram overlays like the ones in ID Cards?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing

Is there any good way to detect the holograms inside security documents like identity cards? I've tried quite a few methods such as sobel filter, laplacian, among others but its still pretty hard to tell if the card has a hologram over it.

Original Image
[image]

From left to right: Laplacian, SobelX, SobelY
[image]

Comment: Edit(24/6/2019): For anyone who wants to do something similar, I recommend using tensorflow object detection API, prepare a large amount of data and start labeling using labelimg. Train using the object detection API, you can read more here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection

Answer (score 2):

What makes a hologram different from the normal print is that it looks different from different angles. It also looks different under different lighting.

I would try to take two pictures with the light coming from different sides. (Or turn the card 180 degrees). Then adjust the background and subtract the two images.

If this is for a mobile application (aka smart phone), the camera needs to take pictures from different angles. The application would have to take sample images while the user moves the phone around the card. It detects the card outline, maps it to a rectangle, and then attempts to substract images until the holograms are found. Apparently the reduced mechanical effort is translated into significantly more complicated software.

Comment: Can this be implemented using basic hardware, like smartphones

Comment: Thanks for the tip, at least i'll have a direction to work with. Been stuck on this for a week with no clear direction.

Comment: Added a thought to my answer. I think moving around is more what users expect, rather than holding still. It would look like a barcode reading app.

Comment: Well the original plan is to capture via video but user has to hold it still but yea will have to add moving around to it as well

Comment: [Here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-14364-4_32)  is a nice example. They capture video with tracking of ID card then create image stack and analyse it.

Comment: @SlawomirOrlowski i've read that example but this only works for visible hologram like stickers that apply to a certain portion but for hologram overlaying the entire id card doesnt really work

Comment: @EdwinCheong: I understand, but general approach with object tracking and image stack on which you can find maximum of differences seems to me a good direction.

Comment: Yea this can be another approach to consider. I'll consider it thanks

Comment: Hello @EdwinCheong, did you manage to find a way? Im on this topic as well. Appreciate if you could shed some light.